# Two level group by, order by using LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, sql-order-by, group-by

What is the LINQ equivalent of the following:

```
SELECT Mytable.A, MyTable.B, SUM(MyTable.C)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Mytable.A, MyTable.B
ORDER BY Mytable.A, MyTable.B
```

This is trivial in SQL, but seems to be very difficult in LINQ. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

I don't have access to Visual Studio right now to test it out but it should look like this:

```
from record in table
group record by new { record.A, record.B } into recGroup
orderby recGroup.Key.A, recGroup.Key.B
select new { recGroup.Key.A, recGroup.Key.B, C = recGroup.Select(p => p.C).Sum() }
```